# Trigonometric functions as elementary functions

Tags: calculus

We know Euler's formula implies that trigonometric functions are elementary functions. However, it forms only complex exponential functions. So, can I say that it is an extension of elementary functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can just call them elementary functions. It's true that in some sense it could be classified as an extension of real elementary functions, but people usually just refer to all trig functions as elementary functions (distinguishing them from something like the [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)).